# javax.validation not validating data objects

Tags: java, validation

I am trying to validate my data objects, but not getting any errors even when invalid input is passed

The below class is used for violation checks.

```
package in.rps.validator;

import in.rps.exception.InvalidRequestException;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class ObjectValidator  {

private static final ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
private static final Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

public <T> void validate(Object o, Class<T> clazz)  {

    if (clazz.isInstance(o)){

        T request = ((T) clazz);
        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(request);
        if (!constraintViolations.isEmpty()){

            throw new InvalidRequestException();
        }

    }else{
        throw new InvalidRequestException();
    }
  }
}
```

Object Class

```
package in.rps.model.response;

import in.rps.model.Dispute;
import in.rps.model.Metadata;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class DisputeHandleResponse  {

@NotNull
Metadata metadata;

@NotNull
Response response;

@NotNull
Dispute dispute;

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
@Size(min =1, max = 35)
String requestId;
}
```

Below are my Gradle dependencies.

```
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.3.7.RELEASE")

compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.el', version: '3.0.1-b12'
compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
```

I have multiple data objects which need to be validated as per requirement, similar to the above data object. However, the problem is that all the Constraint validations are not working.

Method calling the validation function.

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping(path = "/createRequest", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Object> createDispute(@RequestBody String request) {

    Gson g = new Gson();
    DisputeResponse d = g.fromJson(request, DisputeHandleResponse.class);
    d.setRequestId(null);
    objectValidator.validate(d, DisputeHandleResponse.class);

    restService.process(uri, "dispute/create", request);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(Acknowledgement.builder().build());
}
```

Not sure if I am missing anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you run the validation? How does the tested object look like?

Comment: Right, none of these things are actually classes, just snippets.  Please post the full class code of both.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full class code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That update doesn't answer either of my questions. How do you call the validation process? And how does an actual object look like which you're validating? Does it really violate the constraints?

Comment: The validation method is being called part of an API call. And I am explicitly testing for negative cases, so yes the constraints are being violated. For example, I am explicitly passing the request Id as null, which has a @NotNull constraint, and it's still passing.. 
I have added the calling function as well.

Comment: I suggest writing tests with JUnit. You should write multiple tests for different scenarios. For example, one test can pass in valid data and verify that no exception is thrown. Other tests can pass in different kinds of invalid data and verify that the exception is thrown as you expect. These tests have the advantage of providing a minimal example that doesn't involve all of the rest of your application that isn't directly relevant to your question. They will show us exactly what your problem is, assuming the problem is in the `validate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed now. The problem was with the validate method.
Using the below method works fine.

```
public <T> void validate(Object o, Class<T> clazz)  {

    if (clazz.isInstance(o)){
        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations = validator.validate((T)o);
        if (!constraintViolations.isEmpty()){
            throw new InvalidRequestException();
        }
    }else{
        throw new InvalidRequestException();
    }
}
```

Thanks, everyone for your valuable inputs.